# Rehash password using laravel

Tags: laravel-4, bcrypt

i want to know how to decrypt password.suppose i am using Hash::make("admin123") work perfect but how to decrypt? i already tried below two methods

1. `Crypt::decrypt('$2y$10$v2yO0SCt1vOrVZCM8GWRjOuiV1IM3xQbSeq3klaITWVRqsavjaOPI','$2y$10')`
2. `Crypt::decrypt('$2y$10$v2yO0SCt1vOrVZCM8GWRjOuiV1IM3xQbSeq3klaITWVRqsavjaOPI')`

Above two give me "Invalid data."

Actually i want to rehash all password like

```
$users = User->select('password')->where('activated','=',1)->get();
foreach($users as $user){
    // when i register user then i am using Hash::make() mechanism
    // How to rehash $user->password
}
```

Comment: You cannot. That's the point of hashing in the first place.

Comment: so any equivalent mechanism which i can use for node.Js (sails framework)

Comment: It's not the technology that can't do it, it's the hash function that is irreversible by design. Mathematically.

Comment: The point is you save the password after it has been hashed in your db then when the user enters their password to login if the hashed password they entered matches the one in the db then they have the correct password. It's not "unhashed" then checked with the raw password - hope that makes sense!

Comment: You are confusing **hashing** and **encryption**. They're totally different. See [this article](https://danielmiessler.com/study/encoding_encryption_hashing/).

Answer (score 1):

### It's impossible.

More precisely, it's possible, but **it's not fast**. In fact, it's **ridiculously slow**. Ridiculously to the point that **a single "dehash" would take [aeons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aeon)**, if password is hashed correctly. And it's by design, that's precisely why hashes are used with passwords.

Hash-function is a deterministic (i. e. works the same way every time) algorithm that scrambles the given values. It's used for passwords so you don't keep them in plain text, but you still can compare at runtime, whether the given value is the same as the one that has been hashed. The idea is simple: hash is the same for same inputs, hash is different (almost always) for different inputs.

#### Given a hash, you cannot get the source value. It's not encryption.

If you find yourself in a situation when you need to invalidate the existing hashes, write `NULL`s instead. Then, during login, if password hash is `NULL`, then send an email to your user, prompting a password reset due to "a change in your authentication system".

Whether to alert the user on a webpage is up to you, but by telling the user that an email was sent with password reset instructions, you've given a solid clue that the given user exists, this may be useful for a potential attacker. *For the paranoids among us.*